# Validate Host name for HTTP standard compliance in Java

Tags: java, http, apache-commons

I'm trying to build a method that validates a given host name has the right HTTP format according to RFC 9110 [see here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-host-and-authority). Basically, i want this:

```
test.domain.com -> pass
domain:port -> pass
user:pass@test.domain -> fail
test.domain.com/foo -> fail
```

My current implementation is:

```
boolean isValidHost(String host) {
    if (host.contains("/")) return false;
    return UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid("https://" + host);
}
```

where the `UrlValidator` belongs to `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator`. This implementation however accepts the host `user:pass@test.domain`, which is not compliant. Any hints of a better approach?

Note: I rather use a library than custom solutions like regex.